# Why the regular expression is not working properly

Tags: regex, go

I have a validation for first name and while I'm running the "Start*" it will not pass through the code while I pass the "Start$" then it will pass the string. below is the program:-

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
)

func main() {
  FirstName := "Star*"
  var validName = regexp.MustCompile("^[\\p{L}0-9-_&$.,’'\x60()!/ ]*$")
  if !validName.MatchString(FirstName) {
    fmt.Println("--------------", FirstName)
  } else {
    fmt.Println(FirstName)
  }
  FirstName2 := "Star$"
  if !validName.MatchString(FirstName2) {
    fmt.Println("--------------", FirstName2)
  } else {
    fmt.Println(FirstName2)
  }
}
```

[Play ground link](https://play.golang.org/p/p1RHLHEBYnd)

Answer (score 2):

Delete the use `$` inside of the
`^[\\p{L}0-9-_&$.,’'\x60()!/ ]*$` so it would be `^[\\p{L}0-9-_&.,’'\x60()!/ ]*$`.

Comment: $ is a normal character inside the `[]` braces of a character class, so that's not it